# Could not find a version of package matching your minimum-stability. Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-package

I've created a package (`innovareti/password-policy`) and now I am trying to install it, but it is not found:

```
$ composer require innovareti/password-policy
...
  [InvalidArgumentException]                              
  Could not find a version of package innovareti/password-policy
  matching your minimum-stability (dev). Require it with an explicit
  version constraint allowing its desired stability.
```

*(this error keeps ocurring)*

It does have a tag and a release, and I've updated it in packagist but it's still not working, even after the update on packagist is done already for a couple of minutes and [I can see it there](https://packagist.org/packages/innovareti/password-policy) fine.

This is the composer.json of the package:

```
{
  "name": "innovareti/password-policy",
  "description": "A library to intuitively create password policies and validate a subject against them.",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "PasswordPolicy\\Tests\\": "tests/",
      "PasswordPolicy\\": "src/PasswordPolicy/",
      "PasswordPolicy\\Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories",
      "PasswordPolicy\\Models\\": "src/Models"
    }
  },
  "extra":{
    "laravel": [
      "src/PasswordPolicy/Providers/Laravel/PasswordPolicyServiceProvider"
    ]
  },
  "require": {
    "php": "^5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "vendor/bin/phpunit",
    "test-f": "vendor/bin/phpunit --filter"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

My repository is at: https://github.com/innovareti/password-policy

I've tried many things I saw online but nothing worked, can anyone help me?

Comment: It would still be great after you've found the answer yourself, to add your initial composer version to the question (please [edit]), so that it becomes more complete and would allow future users with a similar question to find whether its applicable to them or not (so they won't need to try as many things as you had to).

Comment: Also I edited both your question (a bit) and answer (a bit more). Please check if everything is correct from your perspective and if the references are indeed helpful from your point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that new packages published to packagist need to be installed with composer on version 2<sup>1</sup>.

I ran `composer selfupdate --2` to update my version of composer which was 1.x.

Then required my package by running `composer require innovareti/password-policy` and it worked.

---

1. *Compare "Restricted access to unused packages via the v1 metadata API starting in May 2021"* in [Deprecating Packagist.org support for Composer 1.x](https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/#restricted-access-to-unused-packages-via-the-v1-metadata-api-starting-in-may-2021) (
   [Jordi Boggiano](https://blog.packagist.com/author/seldaek/) for [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/); Feb 2021)

**Further References**

- [Upgrade guides for Composer 1.x to 2.0](https://getcomposer.org/upgrade/UPGRADE-2.0.md) (Composer Documentation)
- [Composer 2.0 Compatibility](https://packagist.com/docs/composer2-compatibility) (Private Packagist Documentation)